# Facebook javascript login using ajax-jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to create fb javascript loging using ajax, php. It works and fetch the required data from facebook. But once user click on login then page gets reloaded twice after login completes and beofre showing data. Here is my code. can anyone point out where is the bug or any link?

```
    <?php
session_start();
$appId = '669340023079549'; 
$appSecret = '390c04c60d19f38e113ea44f268aca44'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://yoursite.com/connect_script/';  //path to script folder
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,email'; //more permissions : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:f   b="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" ><head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>JS/Ajax Facebook Connect</title>
 <script>
 function AjaxResponse()
 {   
    // alert("4");
     var myData = 'connect=1'; //For demo, we will pass a post variable, Check process_facebook.php
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "process_facebook.php",
     dataType:"html",
     data:myData,
     success:function(response){
//       alert(response);
     $("#results").html('<fieldset style="padding:20px">'+response+'</fieldset>'); //Result
 },     error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     $("#results").html('<fieldset style="padding:20px;color:red;">'+thrownError+'</fieldset>'); //Error
    } }); }

function LodingAnimate() //Show loading Image
{
    //alert("3");
    $("#LoginButton").hide(); //hide login button once user authorize the application
    $("#results").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait Connecting...'); //show loading image while we process user
}
 </script></head><body>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
?>
    <div id="results">    </div>
    <div id="LoginButton">
    <div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="return CallAfterLogin();" size="medium" scope="<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>">Connect With Facebook</div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 // alert("1");
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    channelUrl: '<?php echo $return_url; ?>channel.php',
    oauth: true});};

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

        }());

function CallAfterLogin(){
    //alert("2");
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {
              if(data.email == null)
              {
                    //Facbeook user email is empty, you can check something like this.
                    alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                    ResetAnimate();

              }else{
                    AjaxResponse();
              } 
              }); 
         } 
        return true;
    });  

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" size="medium" scope="<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>">Connect With Facebook</div>
```

to

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="return CallAfterLogin();" size="medium" scope="<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>">Connect With Facebook</div>

function CallAfterLogin(){
    //alert("2");
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {
              if(data.email == null)
              {
                    //Facbeook user email is empty, you can check something like this.
                    alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                    ResetAnimate();

              }else{
                    AjaxResponse();
              } 
              }); 
         } 
        return true;
    });  

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, should I also reposition function?

Comment: Ok got it, let me try!

Comment: After modification no change, even now login button remains on screen and not data fetched and shown on browser!

Comment: I updated the code as per your modification but still same issue. Can you please review current version of code given in my question?