# Fetching data from facebook using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can get desired data using facebook api like interest, movies etc. Which comes in below format.

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Movie
                    [name] => 3 Idiots Movie
                    [created_time] => 2012-05-11T13:22:34+0000
                    [id] => 441170255909978
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Movie
                    [name] => Harry Potter
                    [created_time] => 2011-04-11T05:44:14+0000
                    [id] => 156794164312
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Movie
                    [name] => Official Narnia: Voyage of the Dawn Treader
                    [created_time] => 2011-03-10T18:26:57+0000
                    [id] => 190647217857
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Movie general
                    [name] => Harry Porter
                    [created_time] => 2011-03-10T18:26:57+0000
                    [id] => 360697777345
                )
```

How can I get details whic gives only movies and ID so that I can store in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something of  the following form:

```php
foreach (Array['data'] as $var)
{
     $ID=$var['id'];
     $Name=$var['name'];
}
```

**Note:** In `Array['data']`, Array will be the name of the variable that you are saving this data in.

Comment: thank you, my code that print data is `  $user_interest = $facebook->api('/me/movies');
       print_r($user_interest);` so should i take user_interest as Array[]?

Comment: `        foreach ($user_interest as $var)
 {
      $ID=$var['id'];
      $Name=$var['name'];
      print_r($Name);
 }` gives error `Notice:  Undefined index: id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/process_facebook.php on line 26



Notice:  Undefined index: name in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/process_facebook.php on line 27

`

Comment: I think it should be foreach ($user_interest[0] as $var), try that way because it is an array itself that has one element named Data.

Comment: It also does not works gives error `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/process_facebook.php on line 24



Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/process_facebook.php on line 24

`

Comment: My apologies, you should use $user_interest['data'], this should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, if you are expert with ajax then please have a look at : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827633/facebook-javascript-login-using-ajax-jquery`